# replace first column of space delimited file with nth column of comma delimited file

Tags: linux, command-line, awk, ubuntu-12.04

I have a space delimited file that looks like:

```
-1 'xyz
1 'dfg
1 'frt
-1 'pop
```

And a comma delimited file that looks like:

```
1,-1,1,-1
-1,-1,1,-1
1,1,-1,1
1,-1,1,-1
```

Is there a Linux command line one liner to replace the first column of the first file with the nth column on the second file? For instance, if n=2, the new file would become:

```
-1 'xyz
-1 'dfg
1 'frt
-1 'pop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below awk command,

```
$ awk -F'[, ]' 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$2; next}{print a[FNR],$2}' file2 file1 
-1 'xyz
-1 'dfg
1 'frt
-1 'pop
```

Mention the column you want to insert in here `a[FNR]=$2`, in our case it stores the contents of column 2 from file 2 in an associative array.

Comment: Thanks. How would I need to modify that one liner if file 1 had an  unknown/variable number N of columns and I wanted to keep them all, still only replacing column 1?

Answer (score 1):

[`cut`](http://man.cx/cut) and [`paste`](http://man.cx/paste) in bash using [process substitutions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

```
paste -d " " <(cut -d, -f4 file2) <(cut -d " " -f2 file1)
```

```
-1 'xyz
-1 'dfg
1 'frt
-1 'pop
```